# XML Deserialization - Parent element getting attribute value of child

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, restsharp

When deserializing XML using the RestSharp library, if I have an element that contains a nested element with an attribute with the same name, the parent element takes on that attribute value of the nested element - how can I prevent this from happening?

I have several classes (larger than this but this is a reduced form to demonstrate) set up to deserialize XML.

```
[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
[XmlRoot(IsNullable = false)]
public class Base
{
    [XmlAttribute("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("base")]
    [XmlArrayItem("foo")]
    public List<Foo> Foos{ get; set; }

    public Base()
    {
        Foos = new List<Foo>();
    }
}

[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class Foo
{
    [XmlAttribute("style")]
    public string Style { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("bar")]
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    public Foo()
    {           
        Bars = new List<Bar>();
    }
}

[XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
public class Bar
{
    [XmlAttribute("style")]
    public string Style { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("foo")]
    public List<Foo> Foos{ get; set; }

    public Bar()
    {
        Foos = new List<Foo>();
    }
}
```

With XML like:

```
<base>
    <foo>
        <bar style="bold" />
        <bar />
    </foo>
    <foo>
        <bar style="bold" />
        <bar />
    </foo>
</base>
```

When deserialized, I have an instance of Foo where `Foo.Style = "bold"` but I expect `Foo.Style = null`. How can I prevent the parent element from taking the child elements attribute value?

Comment: Are you sure that you want a cycle between the classes? Also, please show how exactly are you deserializing that XML, because I had to mark `Foo` with `[XmlRoot("foo")]` to make it work and after that - it works fine, `style` of deserialized `Foo` is null and it has two `Bar`s, while first has correct `style`.

Comment: I am retrieving and deserializing the XML using the RestSharp library - specifically following the [recommended](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage) method where I am calling something like `Execute<Foo>()`

Comment: I've updated the post to reflect the base of the structure more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with the RestSharp library.

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/752

I have yet to find a solution.